# magento 1.9 problem abandoned car

Tags: magento-1.9, amasty

I installed an amasty "abandoned car" extension, but it doesn't work for me with the following command.

```
/bin/sh /var/www/html/mkt-core/cron.sh
```

I get the following error

[image]

Comment: have you confirm that error comes only after install this extension?

Comment: I really don't know, since I hadn't configured any extensions before

Comment: Then you need to first configured that things.